# How tall is a Wall of Water? Can it be made wider at the cost of making it lower?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, wall

If a wall of water is more than 5 ft tall, could it be shortened to 5 ft to make it wider?

It would still be within the casting range of the caster and is really only meant to be an obstacle for medium and smaller creatures.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## The spell *wall of water* is strict in its dimensions

The 4th-level Sor/Wiz spell *wall of water* [conj] (*Spell Compendium* 235) is [shapeable](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#area), which means the caster

> can shape the spell. **A shaped effect or area can have no dimension smaller than 10 feet.** Many effects or areas are given as cubes to make it easy to model irregular shapes. Three-dimensional volumes are most often needed to define aerial or underwater effects and areas.

Emphasis mine. Further, the spell *wall of water* has an Effect that's

> A straight wall whose area is up to one 10-ft. square/level (S)

Beyond this, the spell makes no mention of any other choices that can be made to resize or reshape it. For instance, there's no option to reduce its height to increase its length or make a dome of water.

That said, there's *probably* nothing wrong with a house rule allowing a caster to shape a *wall of water* more precisely unless, for example, the campaign involves a war against creatures from the Elemental Plane of Fire.

Comment: Somehow reading "Up to" makes it seem ambiguous

Comment: @user2813274 The *wall of water*'s minimum size is a single 10-ft. square and its maximum is a number of 10-ft. squares per caster level. By analogy, were a spell to say that it affected up to 1 cat/level, that would *not* allow the caster to affect instead 2 cat back ends (obviously *equivalent* to 1 cat) or only 1 cat paw (which, as the paw is between 0 and 1 cats, is *up to* 1 cat). It's all cat or no cat in the same way that it's all of a 10-ft. square or none of a 10-ft. square.